# ListView not binding

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

When I run the app, I get two tabs (Im using Tabbed Page) but they are blank.

I have a somewhat complex ViewModel:

```
        public partial class NowPlayingView
{
    const string NowPlayingUrl = "http://api.myserver.com";
    public static List<MoviesItem> MoviesLst { get; set; }

    public NowPlayingView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new MoviesViewModel();
    }
    public class MoviesViewModel
    {
        public MoviesViewModel()
        {
            Action<Dictionary<string, string>> initAction = initialize;
            initAction(new Dictionary<string, string>()
                {
                    {"$format", "json"},
                    {"AccessKey", "f54tg5gf54g-fgs3452-324asdf4"},
                    {"CineplexLanguage", "en-us"}
                });
        }

        public async void initialize(Dictionary<string,string> parameters)
        {
            var data = await (new ApiUtilities().CallGetData<MoviesNowPlaying>(NowPlayingUrl, "/api.svc/MoviesNowPlaying", parameters));
            MoviesLst = data.d.results.Select(x => new MoviesItem() {Header = x.Title, Text = x.MediumPosterImageURL}).ToList();
        }
    }
    public class MoviesItem
    {
        public string Header { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My XAML file look like this:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                       x:Class="XamPlex.MainCategories.NowPlayingView"
             Title="Now Playing">
    <ListView x:Name="MoviesListView" RowHeight="80" BackgroundColor="Transparent" ItemsSource="{Binding MoviesLst}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell.View>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="0" Padding="10">
                            <Label Font="Bold,20" Text="{Binding Header}" TextColor="Indigo"/>
                            <Label Font="16" Text="{Binding Text}" TextColor="Indigo"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell.View>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

I checked the contents of MoviesLst and it contains plenty of data, any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: `BindingSource` sounds like the issue here check this link out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750972(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You are asynchronously populating your ViewModel, so at the time the binding is created there is no data in it.  Change your List to an ObservableCollection - this will allow it to notify the View to update when data is populated.

Answer (score 0):

I do not do a lot of MVC, but I believe the View should have this form:

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    return View();
}
```

I would think your View should be structured something like...

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    var data = await (new ApiUtilities().CallGetData<MoviesNowPlaying>(NowPlayingUrl, "/api.svc/MoviesNowPlaying", parameters));
    var list = data.d.results.Select(x => new MoviesItem() {Header = x.Title, Text = x.MediumPosterImageURL}).ToList();
    return View(list);
}
```

Again, though, I have only worked through the basic tutorials on MVC. I could be misunderstanding your model.

I don't see where you are posting your View anywhere. What I see appears to be the Model.